# Client-side TLS session ticket support in Java 7

Tags: java, session, ssl, client

I want to make a large number of small HTTP requests from a client machine running Java 7 to an external web server over TLS and I would like to use session resumption to make this as efficient as possible.

The web server, however, only appears to support session resumption via the TLS session ticket extension, and so far, I have not seen any documented way of enabling this feature in the javax.net.ssl package.

Does the Java 7 TLS implementation support TLS session tickets on the client side? And if not, could anyone suggest a 3rd party library which does?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if this [isn't even supported on Java 8](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8134497) and has [not been explicitly listed for Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/).

Comment: do those posts include also oracle version?

Comment: Yes, in theory it could be implemented in a non-officially available Oracle version but that is highly unlikely.